# Check char at current/given position in PDCurses/NCurses

Tags: c++, ncurses, pdcurses

Is there a way to check which char is at a given position in the console window? For example if I want to check if there's an asterisk (*) at position (10, 12), how do I do that? Or if I use `move(10, 12);`, how do I check which char is at the current cursor position? I'm using PDCurses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inch family of functions should do that:

```
chtype inch(void);
chtype winch(WINDOW *win);
chtype mvinch(int y, int x);
chtype mvwinch(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);
```