# Check cursor content in C/ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I need a way to check what if the cursor position is empty. I have been searching for hours with no success. Basically if I move the cursor to a location on the window I want to ensure that location is empty before printing something else there. Any ideas?

Comment: Dan Gurkin published a book on NCurses a few years back. Not sure if it's available as an ebook.

Comment: The `inch` family of functions does that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066592/check-char-at-current-given-position-in-pdcurses-ncurses. You should mask the return value to get the character, e.g. `c = A_CHARTEXT & mvinch(row, col)`.